# How can I save an image on my iOS device from NSData?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimage

I have the following code to get an image from a URL and store it in NSData:

```
 NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:pictureurl]];
```

How can I take this data and store it to my iOS device as an image named `myimage.jpg` that I can access later?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create the path for where you want to write the data to

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myimage.png"];
```

The write the `NSData` to file

```
[imageData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

If you want to get the image back its:

```
UIImage *imageFromFile = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Comment: I'm not seeing a writeToFile:atomically:error: on my NSData *imageData. Any idea why?

Comment: @EthanAllen Please learn to make use of the reference docs. A quick scan of the docs for `NSData` will point out the proper method.

Comment: sorry, my mistake. wrote from memory, it doesn't have an error argument